# Tensorflow convolution

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, reshape, convolution

I'm trying to perform a convolution (`conv2d`) on images of variable dimensions. I have those images in form of an 1-D array and I want to perform a convolution on them, but I have a lot of troubles with the shapes.
This is my code of the `conv2d`:

```
tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

where `x` is the input image.
The error is:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 1 for 'Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [1], [5,5,1,32].
```

I think I might reshape `x`, but I don't know the right dimensions. When I try this code:

```
x = tf.reshape(self.x, shape=[-1, 5, 5, 1]) # example
```

I get this:

```
ValueError: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 25 but is 1 for 'Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [1], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [?,5,5,1].
```

Comment: `conv2d` wants data of `shape=[batch, height, width, channels]`, so you would be better off using the images directly rather than flattening them into a 1-D array, if that is an option.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the images don't have a standard height or width, so I can't tell the shape in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use [`conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) with a tensor of rank 1. Here's the description from the doc:

> Computes a 2-D convolution given **4-D** input and filter tensors.

These four dimensions are `[batch, height, width, channels]` (as Engineero already wrote).

If you don't know the dimensions of the image in advance, tensorflow allows to provide a *dynamic* shape:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None, 3], name='x')
with tf.Session() as session:
    print session.run(x, feed_dict={x: data})
```

In this example, a 4-D tensor `x` is created, but only the number of channels is known statically (3), everything else is determined on runtime. So you can pass this `x` into `conv2d`, even if the size is dynamic.

**But there's another problem**. You didn't say your task, but if you're building a convolutional neural network, I'm afraid, you'll need to know the size of the input to determine the size of FC layer after all pooling operations - this size must be static. If this is the case, I think the best solution is actually to scale your inputs to a common size before passing it into a convolutional network.

UPD:

Since it wasn't clear, here's how you can reshape any image into 4-D array.

```
a = np.zeros([50, 178, 3])
shape = a.shape
print shape    # prints (50, 178, 3)
a = a.reshape([1] + list(shape))
print a.shape  # prints (1, 50, 178, 3)
```

Comment: I did as you said, but i got this error: `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50, 178) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?, 3)'`.

Comment: I guess `(150, 178)` is your image size. How many channels does it have? If just one, you need to reshape it to `(1, -1, -1, 1)` - this will a batch of one.

Comment: My bad. I converted the images to rgb and now I get this: `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50, 178, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?, 3)'`

Comment: You forgot a dimension for the batch: `reshape([1, -1, -1, -1])` will make it rank 4.

Comment: Did you mean that i need to reshape like that?: `self.x: tf.reshape(self.__training_set[index], [1, -1, -1, -1])`. Because I can't feed a tensor to feed_dict.

Comment: I assume that your image in `self.__training_set[index]` is a numpy array (if not, you can convert it very easily). Numpy arrays can be reshaped like this - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: Yes, it is a numpy array. With numpy.reshape I can have only one unknown dimension, so only one -1. In fact I get this error: `ValueError: can only specify one unknown dimension`

Comment: Oops, my bad, I gave you the wrong tip. I've updated the answer.